# GNOME3 - Application Window is larger than screen

Tags: gnome-3

I installed Handbrake to do some video conversions on my OpenSUSE 13.1 laptop but when I launch the application it opens and the bottom of the Window is off the viewable screen. Not the end of the world as pressing the super key lets me see the full (if a little small) window but a little annoying.

I tried ALT-F8 and selecting the bottom of the window by pressing the down arrow key but while it selects the bottom of the window it will not re-size it.

My screen resolution is 1366x768. I installed dconf-editor and I can find the ghb application but no settings other than a pointer to the ghb.desktop.

Any on topic ideas welcome.

Comment: Most likely if it won't let you resize it, the window is maximized.

Comment: Interesting point @DanD., it won't allow me to maximise as it is greyed out. I can adjust the top, left and right a little but not the bottom.